# Client accounts Mac os x 10.6 server

Tags: mac-osx-server

I am new to the mac os x server 10.6
I setup a server with the basic services DNS, LDAP, AFP, ...
Everything is working fine. We have 10 mac os x clients that we want to join them to the server. The clients have their computers setup locally with all their files and settings.
How can I integrate these clients into the server and keep all the files and settings locally. The person would login to his computer and then he can share files with all other users of the server and be identified to the server as the local user but with server access.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to use the Workgroup Manager on the server to set up individual accounts for each user (each person, not each machine).  It sounds like maybe you haven't done this yet.  The files and settings are going to be particular to each user on each machine, in other words if two people share a machine, each with their own login, they will each have their own desktop, etc.

If you haven't done this yet, you should set up an Admin account on each machine for your use only.

You might want to consider getting two client machines and doing what you're trying to do in a test environment before you go hooking everyone up and generating expectations and possibly problems.

Answer (score 0):

I´m not 100% percent sure if I understood your question correctly, but it seems you are looking for "mobile accounts" as explained in chapter 8 of [Apple´s "user management" PDF guide](http://images.apple.com/server/macosx/docs/User_Management_v10.6.pdf).